# If my fix contains two java files, I will commit two files in git. Jenkins should generate .zip file with the two .class files but not all files

Tags: java, git, jenkins

we are committing files into git. after commit,it triggers a build automatically in Jenkins. Jenkins is compiling the entire source code and generating the .war file. that's fine.

actually I have another requirement here, Have to get(download) the zip file(contains classes) from jenkins, for the latest/recently committed java files.

zip should contain the .class files of the java files, which are recently submitted/committed.

its like a bug fix/patch creation automation.

Ex: if my fix contains two java files, I will commit two files in git. Jenkins should generate .zip file with the two .class files.

Any Help in this?

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like a really bad idea. Just because you only changed those 2 java files doesn't mean that only the corresponding 2 class files have changed. Let's say for example that one of the .java file contained

```
public static final int MIN_VALUE = 100;
```

and is modified to

```
public static final int MIN_VALUE = 200;
```

All the classes using this constant have changed after the compilation, because the constant value is "inlined" directly in the class file.

Jenkins is there to make sure that the sources compile and the tests pass with the .class files it has generated and stored in the war file. If you want something safe and robust, you should not take only half of the produced artefacts. Take the generated war file, and reinstall it completely, instead of patching individual .class files.

Comment: yes may be..but actually our requirement is like that. have to generate point patches as well as inline patches also.